I keep getting errors after filling in constructor parameters for a slot game. How do I fix this?
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.14;

import "./GameMasterclass.sol";
import "./IClaimManager.sol";
import "./IHistoryManager.sol";
import "./IHouse.sol";


contract Slots is GameMasterclass {

    // History Manager
    IHistoryManager public immutable history;

    // Max Multiplier To Buy-In For Spins
    uint8 public numGameModes;

    /** Reel Info */
    uint8[] public reel1;
    uint8[] public reel2;
    uint8[] public reel3;

    // Game Struct
    struct Game {
        /** Which GameMode */
        uint8 gameMode;

        /** Player */
        address player;

        /** Amount Bet */
        uint256 betAmount;

        /** Total Amount For House */
        uint256 amountForHouse;

        /** Number of spins */
        uint8 numSpins;

        /** Final Output -- reels */
        uint8[] num0;
        uint8[] num1;
        uint8[] num2;

        /** Payouts */
        uint256 payout;
        uint256 jackpotPayout;

        /** Whether or not the game has ended and the VRF has called back */
        bool hasEnded;
    }

    // mapping from GameID => Game
    mapping ( uint256 => Game ) public games;

    // request ID => GameID
    mapping ( uint256 => uint256 ) private requestToGame;

    /** Platform Fee Taken Out Of Buy In */
    uint256 public platformFee = 100;

    /** Fee Taken To Add To Each Jackpot */
    uint256 public jackpotFee = 10;

    /** Fee Denominator */
    uint256 private constant FEE_DENOM = 10_000;

    /** List of all used game ids */
    uint256[] public usedGameIds;
    mapping ( uint256 => bool ) public isUsedGameId;

    /** Maps three random numbers to a payout */
    mapping ( uint8 => mapping ( uint8 => mapping ( uint8 => uint256 ) ) ) public payout;

    /** Payout Denom */
    uint256 public constant PAYOUT_DENOM = 10_000; // 0.01x precision (payout of 100 = 1%, 10,000 = 1x, 1,000,000 = 100x)

    // Game Mode Structure
    struct GameMode {
        uint256 buyIn;
        uint256 jackpotAmount;
        uint256 jackpotAllocation;
    }

    // gas per spin
    uint32 public base_spin_gas = 640_000;
    uint32 public gas_per_spin  = 60_000;

    // buy in gas per spin
    uint256 public minBuyInGas;
    uint256 public buyInGasPerSpin;

    // min spins
    uint256 public MIN_SPINS = 1;
    uint256 public MAX_SPINS = 30;

    // Maps a multiplier to a bonus jackpot payout
    // NOTE: map it to indexes in reel0,1,2 -- so we can give more jackpot bonuses to pots like BNB-BNB-BNB (0.06% chance)
    mapping ( uint8 => GameMode ) public gameModes;

    // Bonus Jackpot Total Allocation
    uint256 public gameModeTotalJackpotAllocation;

    // Free Spin Contract, That Can Place Bets FOR Other Users
    mapping ( address => bool ) public isFreeSpinContract;

    /** Locks changes to odds */
    bool public oddsLocked;

    /// @notice emitted after the platform fee has been changed
    event SetPlatformFee(uint256 newFee);
    event SetJackpotFee(uint256 newFee);

    /// @notice emitted after a random request has been sent out
    event RandomnessRequested(uint256 gameId);

    /// @notice emitted after a game has been started at a specific table
    event GameStarted(address indexed user, uint256 gameId);

    /// @notice Emitted after the VRF comes back with the index of the winning player
    event GameEnded(
        address indexed user, 
        uint256 gameId, 
        uint8 gameMode,
        uint256 payout,
        uint256 jackpotBonus
    );

    /// @notice Emitted if the fulfilRandomWords function needs to return out for any reason
    event FulfilRandomFailed(uint256 requestId, uint256 gameId, uint256[] randomWords);

    /// @notice Emitted when the reel data is updated, emits the odds associated with the reel data
    event OddsLocked();

    constructor(

        /** Constructor Arguments For Master Class */
        uint256 versionNo_,
        uint256 GAME_ID_,

        /** History Manager */
        address history_,

        /** Game Configs */
        uint8[] memory reel1_,
        uint8[] memory reel2_,
        uint8[] memory reel3_,
        uint256[] memory buyIns,
        uint256[] memory jackpotAllocations,

        uint256 minBuyInGas_,
        uint256 buyInGasPerSpin_

    ) GameMasterclass(GAME_ID_, versionNo_) {

        // setup history manager
        history = IHistoryManager(history_);

        // set game mode data
        gameModes[0] = GameMode({
            buyIn: buyIns[0],
            jackpotAmount: 0,
            jackpotAllocation: jackpotAllocations[0]
        });
        gameModes[1] = GameMode({
            buyIn: buyIns[1],
            jackpotAmount: 0,
            jackpotAllocation: jackpotAllocations[1]
        });
        gameModes[2] = GameMode({
            buyIn: buyIns[2],
            jackpotAmount: 0,
            jackpotAllocation: jackpotAllocations[2]
        });
        gameModes[3] = GameMode({
            buyIn: buyIns[3],
            jackpotAmount: 0,
            jackpotAllocation: jackpotAllocations[3]
        });
        gameModeTotalJackpotAllocation = jackpotAllocations[0] + jackpotAllocations[1] + jackpotAllocations[2] + jackpotAllocations[3];
        numGameModes = 4;

        // set reels
        reel1 = reel1_;
        reel2 = reel2_;
        reel3 = reel3_;

        // set gas info
        minBuyInGas     = minBuyInGas_;     // 0.03 ether;  // = 0.001 ether;
        buyInGasPerSpin = buyInGasPerSpin_; // 0.001 ether; // = 0.00005 ether;
    }

    // set min spins
    function setMinSpins(uint256 newMin) external onlyOwner {
        MIN_SPINS = newMin;
    }
    function setMaxSpins(uint256 newMax) external onlyOwner {
        MAX_SPINS = newMax;
    }

    function setBuyInGasInfo(uint256 newMin, uint256 newGasPerSpin) external onlyOwner {
        minBuyInGas = newMin;
        buyInGasPerSpin = newGasPerSpin;
    }

    function setVRFGasInfo(uint32 newBase, uint32 newGasPerSpin) external onlyOwner {
        base_spin_gas = newBase;
        gas_per_spin = newGasPerSpin;
    }

    // set bonus jackpot allocation
    function setGameModeJackpotAllocation(uint8 gameMode, uint256 allocation) external onlyOwner {
        require(
            gameMode <= numGameModes,
            'Invalid Game Mode'
        );
        require(
            allocation > 0,
            'Invalid Allocation'
        );
        unchecked {
            gameModeTotalJackpotAllocation = ( ( gameModeTotalJackpotAllocation + allocation ) - gameModes[gameMode].jackpotAllocation );
        }
        gameModes[gameMode].jackpotAllocation = allocation;
    }

    function addNewGameMode(uint256 buyIn, uint256 newAllocation) external onlyOwner {
        require(
            newAllocation > 0,
            'Invalid Allocation'
        );
        require(
            buyIn > 0,
            'Invalid Buy In'
        );

        // increase total allocation
        unchecked {
            gameModeTotalJackpotAllocation += newAllocation;
        }
        
        // set allocation
        gameModes[numGameModes] = GameMode({
            buyIn: buyIn,
            jackpotAmount: 0,
            jackpotAllocation: newAllocation
        });

        // increment num game modes
        unchecked {
            ++numGameModes;
        }
    }

    function removeLatestGameMode() external onlyOwner {
        require(
            numGameModes > 1,
            'Cannot Remove Only Game Mode'
        );

        // decrement max game mode
        unchecked {
            --numGameModes;
        }

        unchecked {
            // reduce total allocation
            gameModeTotalJackpotAllocation -= gameModes[numGameModes].jackpotAllocation;

            // roll over any remaining jackpot to the new game mode
            gameModes[numGameModes - 1].jackpotAmount += gameModes[numGameModes].jackpotAmount;
        }

        // delete all data associated with current game mode
        delete gameModes[numGameModes];   
    }

    function setBuyIn(uint8 gameMode, uint256 newBuyIn) external onlyOwner {
        require(
            gameMode < numGameModes, 
            'Invalid Game Mode'
        );
        gameModes[gameMode].buyIn = newBuyIn;
    }

    function setPlatformFee(uint256 newPlatform) external onlyOwner {
        require(
            newPlatform <= FEE_DENOM / 10,
            'Cannot Exceed 10%'
        );
        platformFee = newPlatform;
        emit SetPlatformFee(newPlatform);
    }

    function setJackpotFee(uint256 newJackpot) external onlyOwner {
        require(
            newJackpot <= FEE_DENOM / 20,
            'Cannot Exceed 5%'
        );
        jackpotFee = newJackpot;
        emit SetJackpotFee(newJackpot);
    }

    function lockOdds() external onlyOwner {
        oddsLocked = true;
        emit OddsLocked();
    }

    function setIsFreeSpinContract(address freeSpinContract_, bool isFree) external onlyOwner {
        isFreeSpinContract[freeSpinContract_] = isFree;
    }

    function setReels(
        uint8[] calldata reel1_,
        uint8[] calldata reel2_,
        uint8[] calldata reel3_
    ) external onlyOwner {
        require(
            oddsLocked == false,
            'Odds Are Locked'
        );
        reel1 = reel1_;
        reel2 = reel2_;
        reel3 = reel3_;
    }

    function batchSetPayouts(
        uint8[] calldata coins0,
        uint8[] calldata coins1,
        uint8[] calldata coins2,
        uint256[] calldata payoutMultiplier
    ) external onlyOwner {
        require(
            oddsLocked == false,
            'Odds are locked'
        );
        uint len = coins0.length;
        require(
            len == coins1.length,
            'Invalid Length 0-1'
        );
        require(
            len == coins2.length,
            'Invalid Length 0-2'
        );
        require(
            len == payoutMultiplier.length,
            'Invalid Length 0-payout'
        );

        for (uint i = 0; i < len;) {
            // set payout
            payout[coins0[i]][coins1[i]][coins2[i]] = payoutMultiplier[i];
            unchecked { ++i; }
        }
    }

    function addToJackpotPayout(uint8 gameMode) external payable {
        require(
            gameMode < numGameModes,
            'Invalid Game Mode'
        );
        unchecked {
            gameModes[gameMode].jackpotAmount += msg.value;
        }
    }

    function pullLever(
        uint8 gameMode,
        uint8 numSpins,
        uint256 gameId, 
        uint256 partnerId,
        string calldata ref,
        address player
    ) external payable {
        require(
            !paused,
            'Paused'
        );
        require(
            gameId > 0,
            'Zero Game Id'
        );
        uint8 _numSpins = numSpins;
        uint256 _gameId = gameId;
        require(
            numSpins >= MIN_SPINS && numSpins <= MAX_SPINS,
            'Invalid Spin Count'
        );
        require(
            isValidGameId(_gameId),
            'Game ID Already Used'
        );
        address player_ = player;
        uint8 gameMode_ = gameMode;
        if (msg.sender != player_) {
            require(
                isFreeSpinContract[msg.sender],
                'Invalid Caller'
            );
        }

        // calculate the bet amount
        uint256 betAmount = gameModes[gameMode_].buyIn;
        uint256 totalBetAmount = betAmount * _numSpins;
        uint256 gasRequired = minBuyInGas + ( _numSpins * buyInGasPerSpin );
        require(
            msg.value >= totalBetAmount + gasRequired,
            'Invalid Ether Sent For BuyIn Gas'
        );
        require(
            gameMode_ < numGameModes,
            'INVALID GAME MODE'
        );

        // send fee to chainlink
        TransferHelper.safeTransferETH(manager.chainlinkFeeReceiver(), msg.value - totalBetAmount);

        // take platform fee out of the buy in
        uint256 platformFeeAmount = ( totalBetAmount * platformFee ) / FEE_DENOM;

        // determine value to add to each of the jackpot pools
        uint256 jackPotAmount = ( totalBetAmount * jackpotFee ) / FEE_DENOM;

        // loop through multipliers
        for (uint8 i = 0; i < numGameModes;) {
            unchecked {
                // ignore round-off, costs more to validate the amount than the wei stuck in the contract
                gameModes[i].jackpotAmount += ( jackPotAmount * gameModes[i].jackpotAllocation ) / gameModeTotalJackpotAllocation;
                ++i; 
            }
        }

        // send to platform receiver
        _processFee(platformFeeAmount, player, partnerId, ref);

        // save game data
        games[_gameId].gameMode = gameMode_;
        games[_gameId].player = player_;
        games[_gameId].betAmount = betAmount; // STORE DATA SHOWING HOW MUCH IS THERE AFTER FEES
        games[_gameId].amountForHouse = totalBetAmount - ( platformFeeAmount + jackPotAmount );
        games[_gameId].numSpins = _numSpins;
        games[_gameId].num0 = new uint8[](_numSpins);
        games[_gameId].num1 = new uint8[](_numSpins);
        games[_gameId].num2 = new uint8[](_numSpins);

        // set history data
        history.addData(GAME_ID, player_, totalBetAmount, _gameId, versionNo);

        // process points
        _registerBet(player_, totalBetAmount, partnerId);

        // fetch random number
        _requestRandom(_gameId, _numSpins, base_spin_gas + ( gas_per_spin * _numSpins ));

        // add to list of used game ids
        usedGameIds.push(_gameId);
        isUsedGameId[_gameId] = true;
        
        // emit event
        emit GameStarted(player_, _gameId);
    }


    function _requestRandom(uint256 gameId, uint8 numSpins, uint32 gas) internal {

        // request random words from RNG contract
        uint256 requestId = IRNG(manager.RNG()).requestRandom(
            gas, // callback gas limit is dependent num of random values & gas used in callback
            uint32(numSpins * uint8(3)) // the number of random results to return
        );

        // require that the requestId is unused
        require(
            requestToGame[requestId] == 0,
            'RequestId In Use'
        );

        // map this request ID to the game it belongs to
        requestToGame[requestId] = gameId;

        // set data in house
        IHouse(manager.house()).randomRequested();

        // emit event
        emit RandomnessRequested(gameId);
    }

    /**
        Callback to provide us with randomness
     */
    function fulfillRandomWords(
        uint256 requestId,
        uint256[] calldata randomWords
    ) external override onlyRNG {

        // get game ID from requestId
        uint256 gameId = requestToGame[requestId];
        
        // if faulty ID, remove
        if (
            gameId == 0 || 
            games[gameId].player == address(0) || 
            games[gameId].hasEnded == true ||
            (numOptionsReel1() * numOptionsReel2() * numOptionsReel3()) == 0
        ) {
            emit FulfilRandomFailed(requestId, gameId, randomWords);
            return;
        }

        // set game has ended
        games[gameId].hasEnded = true;

        // clear storage
        delete requestToGame[requestId];

        // resolve request in house
        IHouse(manager.house()).randomRequestResolved();

        // save any jackpot bonuses to be distributed after
        uint256 jackpotBonus = 0;

        // total to pay out for the house and total to send the house
        uint256 totalToPayout = 0;

        // NOTE: we need to generate THREE random numbers, one for each Reel
        // and if there are 50 entries in a reel, we need to mod 50
        // we need to ensure that the weights for each entry make sense
        for (uint i = 0; i < games[gameId].numSpins;) {

            // fetch index (coin) of reel array
            uint8 index1 = getMinIndexReel1(randomWords[i * 3] % numOptionsReel1());
            uint8 index2 = getMinIndexReel2(randomWords[(i * 3) + 1] % numOptionsReel2());
            uint8 index3 = getMinIndexReel3(randomWords[(i * 3) + 2] % numOptionsReel3());

            // save indexes to state
            games[gameId].num0[i] = index1;
            games[gameId].num1[i] = index2;
            games[gameId].num2[i] = index3;

            // // if payout exists, user won
            if (payout[index1][index2][index3] > 0) {

                // determine if payout is a jackpot
                if (index1 == 0 && index2 == 0 && index3 == 0) {
                    // payout is a jackpot
                    jackpotBonus += gameModes[games[gameId].gameMode].jackpotAmount;
                    gameModes[games[gameId].gameMode].jackpotAmount = 0; // reset bonus
                }

                // increment data, add to total payout
                unchecked {
                    totalToPayout += ( payout[index1][index2][index3] * games[gameId].betAmount ) / PAYOUT_DENOM;
                }

            }

            unchecked { ++i; }
        }

        if (totalToPayout > 0) {
            // there is a payout, we won something

            if (totalToPayout >= games[gameId].amountForHouse) {
                // the user has won more than we are giving to the house
                // this means we need to send them (to claim manager) amountForHouse directly
                // and only request that the house `payout` the difference!

                // add to user's claim manager the amount for the house
                IClaimManager(manager.claimManager()).credit{value: games[gameId].amountForHouse}(
                    GAME_ID,
                    games[gameId].player
                );

                // get the difference
                uint256 remaining = totalToPayout - games[gameId].amountForHouse;
                if (remaining > 0) {
                    // payout the rest from the house
                    IHouse(manager.house()).payout(GAME_ID, games[gameId].player, remaining);
                }
                
            } else {
                // the user has won less than we are giving to the house
                // pay them out directly in full, send whatever is left over to the house

                // pay user directly their totalToPayout
                IClaimManager(manager.claimManager()).credit{value: totalToPayout}(
                    GAME_ID,
                    games[gameId].player
                );

                // calculate remaining left for the house
                uint256 remaining = games[gameId].amountForHouse - totalToPayout;

                // send the remaining to the house
                IHouse(manager.house()).houseProfit{value: remaining }(GAME_ID);
            }

            // save payout info
            games[gameId].payout = totalToPayout;

            // set history special user
            history.setAmountWon(games[gameId].player, GAME_ID, gameId, totalToPayout + jackpotBonus);
        
        } else {

            // we won nothing, send the house everything
            IHouse(manager.house()).houseProfit{value: games[gameId].amountForHouse }(GAME_ID);

        }

        // if user won the jackpot, also credit the jackpot to the user
        if (jackpotBonus > 0) {

            // save jackpot info
            games[gameId].jackpotPayout = jackpotBonus;

            // send to user's claim manager
            IClaimManager(manager.claimManager()).credit{value: jackpotBonus}(
                GAME_ID,
                games[gameId].player
            );
        }

        // emit game ended event
        emit GameEnded(games[gameId].player, gameId, games[gameId].gameMode, totalToPayout, jackpotBonus);
    }

    function optionsReel1() external view returns (uint8[] memory) {
        return reel1;
    }

    function optionsReel2() external view returns (uint8[] memory) {
        return reel2;
    }

    function optionsReel3() external view returns (uint8[] memory) {
        return reel3;
    }

    function getMinIndexReel1(uint256 random) public view returns (uint8) {
        uint8 len = uint8(reel1.length);
        uint8 index = len;
        for (uint8 i = 0; i < len;) {
            if (random < reel1[i]) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
            unchecked { ++i; }
        }
        return index;
    }

    function getMinIndexReel2(uint256 random) public view returns (uint8) {
        uint8 len = uint8(reel2.length);
        uint8 index = len;
        for (uint8 i = 0; i < len;) {
            if (random < reel2[i]) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
            unchecked { ++i; }
        }
        return index;
    }

    function getMinIndexReel3(uint256 random) public view returns (uint8) {
        uint8 len = uint8(reel3.length);
        uint8 index = len;
        for (uint8 i = 0; i < len;) {
            if (random < reel3[i]) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
            unchecked { ++i; }
        }
        return index;
    }

    function getJackpots() external view returns (uint256[] memory jackpots) {
        jackpots = new uint256[](numGameModes);
        for (uint8 i = 0; i < numGameModes; i++) {
            jackpots[i] = gameModes[i].jackpotAmount;
        }
    }

    function getJackpotTotalPayouts() external view returns (uint256[] memory jackpots) {
        jackpots = new uint256[](numGameModes);
        for (uint8 i = 0; i < numGameModes; i++) {
            jackpots[i] = gameModes[i].jackpotAmount + ( ( payout[0][0][0] * gameModes[i].buyIn ) / PAYOUT_DENOM );
        }
    }

    function numOptionsReel1() public view returns (uint256) {
        return reel1[reel1.length - 1];
    }

    function numOptionsReel2() public view returns (uint256) {
        return reel2[reel2.length - 1];
    }

    function numOptionsReel3() public view returns (uint256) {
        return reel3[reel3.length - 1];
    }

    function getPayout(uint8 coin1, uint8 coin2, uint8 coin3) public view returns (uint256) {
        return payout[coin1][coin2][coin3];
    }

    function isValidGameId(uint256 gameId) public view returns (bool) {
        return games[gameId].hasEnded == false && games[gameId].player == address(0) && isUsedGameId[gameId] == false;
    }

    function viewAllUsedGameIds() external view returns (uint256[] memory) {
        return usedGameIds;
    }

    function numUsedGameIDs() external view returns (uint256) {
        return usedGameIds.length;
    }

    function batchCallIsUsedGameId(uint256[] calldata gameIds) external view returns (bool[] memory isUsed) {
        uint len = gameIds.length;
        isUsed = new bool[](len);
        for (uint i = 0; i < len;) {
            isUsed[i] = isUsedGameId[gameIds[i]];
            unchecked { ++i; }
        }
    }

    function paginateUsedGameIDs(uint256 start, uint256 end) external view returns (uint256[] memory) {
        uint count = 0;
        uint256[] memory ids = new uint256[](end - start);
        for (uint i = start; i < end;) {
            ids[count] = usedGameIds[i];
            unchecked { ++i; ++count; }
        }
        return ids;
    }

    function getMinBuyInGas(uint8 numSpins) public view returns (uint256) {
        return minBuyInGas + ( numSpins * buyInGasPerSpin );
    }

    function quoteValue(uint8 gameMode, uint8 numSpins) external view returns (uint256) {
        return ( gameModes[gameMode].buyIn * numSpins ) + getMinBuyInGas(numSpins);
    }

    function getGameInfo(uint256 gameId) external view returns (
        address player,
        uint8 gameMode,
        uint8 numSpins,
        uint8[] memory num0,
        uint8[] memory num1,
        uint8[] memory num2,
        uint256 totalPayout,
        uint256 jackpotPayout,
        bool hasEnded
    ) {
        player = games[gameId].player;
        gameMode = games[gameId].gameMode;
        numSpins = games[gameId].numSpins;
        num0 = games[gameId].num0;
        num1 = games[gameId].num1;
        num2 = games[gameId].num2;
        totalPayout = games[gameId].payout;
        jackpotPayout = games[gameId].jackpotPayout;
        hasEnded = games[gameId].hasEnded;
    }
}


Specify the exact error message you are getting.
